# Laravel: Single or Multiple mysql tables for different Announcement types

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design

Good day to everyone reading this. I do need advice on a project I'm working on.
I'm relatively new to programming in PHP and MySQL, and I heard working on projects is the best way to brush up my skills.

The project is a simple announcements project where users can login register new announcements.
Now, each announcement is based upon a category e.g. Birthdays, Weddings, Social functions, Court hearing etc.

One thing I'm currently caught up with is how the MYSQL table structure would look like.
For instance, if a user wants to make a birthday post, all the user clicks is birthday and fills a form with relevant information. If a user wants to make a wedding post, the user clicks weddings and fills a form with relevant information.

However, the way I have this setup, I have a different data table for each announcement. 
i.e. Each announcement type is stored in its own table.

For instance for birthdays, I created a Birthday model with a BirthdaysController 
For weddings, I created a Wedding model with a WeddingsController. 
For graduation, I created a Graduation model with a GraduationController.

But some of the announcements share similar attributes like name, title, etc.

But this however would imply repeating a lot of code since they share similar attributes e.g. a birthday announcement would most likely be similar to a graduation announcement.

My first question is how do I limit the number of tables I have to create and reduce code so it doesn't look repetitive.

From my point of view, I have way too many models and controller. More so, I find I am repeating codes, and in "Object Oriented Boot camp" from Laracast, I can vividly remember Jeff stated this is a bad practice.
So I really am looking for a better way to do this.
I know this is quite lengthy, but please I do need help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: I think separating them is absolutely fine. The second  you will need to add some more specific information about any of the announcements you will be really happy you have them in separated. If there's a few fields that are shared I don't think that's a good enough reason to make some complicated system of sharing these information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd make use of the relational functionality of MySQL (it being a relational database).

If you can identify a superset of attributes for each announcement type - i.e. all attributes for all announcements types combined into a unique list, then make this your announcements table.

e.g.

```
announcement_id: a unique id for each announcement. can just be an auto incremented number
announcement_date: date
announcement_type: (see below)
announcement_title: the announcement headline / title
announcement_detail: the detail text for the announcement
announcement_user: name of the person adding the announcement (think about user lists and authentication and things for this as well...)
```

Then add an announcements_type table with the different types of announcement that you allow in your announcements table:

```
announcement_type_id: a type id could just be a single letter, e.g B=Birthday, G=Graduation,W=Wedding.
announcement_type_description: a user friendly name for the announcement type, e.g Birthday, Graduation, Wedding
```

The records in your two tables could therefore be:

Types table:

```
id    description
W     Wedding
B     Birthday
G     Graduation
```

Announcements table:

```
id    date       type  title                     detail                                                        user
1     18090212   B     Abe Lincoln's birthday    Birthday of the 16th US president                             John Doe
2     19810729   W     Royal Wedding             Wedding of Prince Charles and Diana Spencer in London   Fred Bloggs
```

This is not meant to be a full solution, but will hopefully give you some ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Although you said you were a beginner, I think choosing such a challenge means you are up to the task.

You want to have announcements, where each type may (or may not) have some extra columns. I would suggest creating a single table for all your announcements, since they share some attributes (title, type, description, date, status, etc.).

So you put all common fields into the same table, then create a table called something like 'announcement_data' or 'extra' or whatever you want. I will call it Extra for this explanation.

Extra belongsTo Announcement & Announcement hasMany Extra. Then when you save an announcement, according to the type, you will display some extra fields in the form, e.g: 'witness', 'bride', etc. You get them from the controller

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    $announcement = Announcement::create([
        'title' = $request->title,
        'type' => $request->type,
        ... //all common fields (description, status, date, etc.)
    ]);

    //save extra fields
    //according to the type of event, you should find a way to know which extra field is needed e.g:

    //assuming it's a wedding
    $announcement->extra()->saveMany([
        new Extra(['field' => 'bride', 'value' => $request->bride]),
        new Extra(['field' => 'groom', 'value' => $request->groom])
    ]);
}
```

How to display your data later on?

```
@foreach($announcement->extra as $extra)
    {{ $extra->field }} : {{ $extra->value }}
@endforeach
```

Well that was just another road leading to Rome.

Comment: The problem I see with this design is a) you might've normalized title, but in the same breath you made all other attributes in a way where (at least) the "field" value will in practice be duplicated over and over and over b) you have all values saved as text which is not optimized for a lot of data types.